# Error 400: Bad request - For shopping application

Tags: html, node.js, angular

Im deploying online shopping website, and typically am able to add items to my cart and proceed to checkout. But now there's an issue with site on log in.

My error is:

```
Error 400: Bad request
```

This seems so generic, I don't know what to do.

I tried accessing it on another computer and it works fine. What could be the cause of this? How can I fix it? Big blocker for me right now. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: With this error, usually there's a problem with the request that your browser is sending to the website's server, What is the request you're making?

Comment: Also might want to check out our [code of conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct). It's important to ask good questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this error, the problem is usually with the request that your browser is sending to the website's server. It could be due to corrupted or maybe incomplete data, which could potentially be linked to cached data in your browser causing conflicts.

- Check your computer's **internet connection** and look for irregularities.
- Check your **Browser Cache and Cookies** and clear it. Cached data in your browser could be making some conflicts.
- Check your **browser's compatibility**.

Hope this helps

Comment: Oh it was my browser cache. It had so much in it. I'm no longer getting the error! Thank you, thank you so much! Took so long on this blocker

Comment: If it works, you can add it as the solution to your question. With the Check box.

Comment: Oh sorry, this is still so new

Comment: We've all been there. This specific issue happens a lot when you aren't keeping your browser clean/updated, can really slow things down and cause problems.

Comment: Yeah I will work on fixing that up. This was huge issue